# how to step down the voltage from 100V(after a FullWaverectifier) to 1V without affected by noise

Tags: step-down

How to step down the voltage from 100V(after a Full Wave rectifier) to 1V without affected by the noise?

**The task**

I have 70V<sub>rms</sub> sine wave, I rectified it with full wave rectifier. So  the output is  100V<sub>p</sub>.
I will divide it down to 1V using voltage divider (0-100V to 0-1V).
How could I add a 1.4V DC bias to the output of the voltage divided ?

Briefly:
$$ 70V_\text{rms} \Longrightarrow  0-100V_\text{p} \Longrightarrow 0-1V \Longrightarrow 1.4-2.4V$$

- I have a 5V DC I could used it in the biasing

**The solution I used** 
[image]

I try with voltage divider and I had a lot of noise since 10V will give my 0.1 Vout.

**Here is my project** [image]

When the voltage is 56Vrms, I get the following results ( the green is the signal at PWM pin1 and the yellow is at R6 -the AM demodulator- )
[image]

The voltage at pin 1 of the PWM IC (UC3526AN) have to be 1.4VDC bias with 1Vpp  when the input voltage is 100Vpp but it is not.
The following is the real measurements at pin 1.

**The results and the problems**

- At about 20Vrms input
  [image]
- At about 30Vrms input
  [image]
- At about 68Vrms input
  [image]
- At about 100Vrms input
  [image]

Comment: One would normally use a transformer, full-wave rectifier and a voltage regulator.

Comment: It's unclear what you expect to achieve by what you did. Try giving more detail of what you want.

Comment: @Andyaka I add more information.

Comment: @Golaž I am measuring the voltage using NI CompactDAQ and need to read it as it is after the bridge without any changes(no smoothing capacitor or voltage regulator )

Comment: All I see are results (scope pics). What are the problems?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. remove R1 (pin 1 & GND)and R2 (2.7K) form 5V ref. supply
2. Remove the rectifier ground.
2. connect approx. 1.2 K res. between negative of rectified supply and ground.
3. connect approx. 3.3 K between 1.2 K and 5V ref.(u may have to fiddle with to get exact 1.4 V)
4. pref. connect 100 micro cap. across 1.2 K res.
5. and try
VTIgole